# multi processing untar a tbz2 file in linux

Tags: multiprocessing, tar, unzip

I have a really high end machine with high number of cores
And I want to unzip a really big tbz2 file, the default one uses only one core

Is there a way to unzip which will use all the CPU cores something like the -j32 option of make.

`tar xjpf abc.tbz2 -C $PWD -j32`

Answer (score 0):

I have an alias for this myself, which makes tar use the parallelized bzip2 decoder [`lbzip2`](https://lbzip2.org/):

```bash
sudo apt install lbzip2  # on Debian-like systems
alias tbz2='tar --use-compress-program=lbzip2'
tbz2 xjpf abc.tbz2 -C $PWD
```

You could also specify another parallel bzip2 decoder like [`ibzip2`](https://github.com/mxmlnkn/indexed_bzip2/tree/master/python/indexed_bzip2#command-line-tool) but until I have optimized that further lbzip2 is probably the fastest, easily accessible, and more time-tested solution. Note that others like [`pbzip2`](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/) only compress in parallel but cannot decompress in parallel.